# setInterval- Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Trying to loop a function.

It's a simple text animation - The text will

1.Fade in left letter by letter and then

2.Fade out up letter by letter.

3.This will repeat, but the text will appear again at another random location on the 
      page.

When I set the interval delay to 1000, the text appears 4 times in all with a gap of 1 sec each. The first time, the text appears with fade in left, the second & third the text just flashes as a whole and finally, the fade out happens letter by letter.

So, I set the delay to 4700. The animation works as desired, but it is not looping.

http://jsfiddle.net/y5C4G/3/

The callback function in textillate wasn't working too, so i chose setInterval.

**HTML :**

```
<span class="brand">
                <h1>
                    <ul class="texts">
                        <li>E L Y S I U M</li>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                </h1>
            </span>
```

**JS :**

```
$(window).bind("load", function () {

            function ShowBrand() {
            var docHeight = $(document).height();
            var docWidth = $(document).width();

            $newSpan = $(".brand");
            spanHeight = $newSpan.height();
            spanWidth = $newSpan.width();

            maxHeight = docHeight - spanHeight;
            maxWidth = docWidth - spanWidth;

            $newSpan.show().css({
                top: Math.floor(Math.random() * maxHeight), 
                left: Math.floor(Math.random() * maxWidth)
            }).textillate({
            in: {effect:'fadeInLeft'},
            out: {effect:'fadeOutUp'}
            });                
        }            

        setInterval(ShowBrand,4700);           

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so sure about what you want to achieve exactly on your animation, but I guess what you would like to do is something like this:

**DEMO:**http://jsfiddle.net/YKebf/9/

```
loadTextillate(jQuery);

$newSpan = $(".brand");
$newSpan.show().textillate({ in : {
        effect: 'fadeInLeft'
    },
    out: {
        effect: 'fadeOutUp',
        callback: function () {
            ShowBrand(); //set as a callback function
        }
    },
    loop: true
});

function ShowBrand() {

    var docHeight  = $(document).height();
    var docWidth   = $(document).width();
    var spanHeight = $newSpan.height();
    var spanWidth  = $newSpan.width();
    var maxHeight  = docHeight - spanHeight;
    var maxWidth   = docWidth - spanWidth;
    var newPosTop  = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxHeight);
    var newPosLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxWidth);
    console.log("New Position",newPosTop,newPosLeft);
    $newSpan.css({
        top:newPosTop,
        left:newPosLeft 
    });
}
```

CSS:

```
.brand{
    position:absolute;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what is needed, but i dont want to modify the original textillate.js. is there any other way

Comment: @user3615588, Thanks. I found a good way. You can set a callback function. http://jsfiddle.net/YKebf/9/

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** As mentioned by naota, you can set a callback. By doing this you will not be needing any `setInterval` and also you might not have to modify any code in plugin file in my case. See the updated demo : http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/y5C4G/6/

Instead of initializing `textillate` in each interval, why not just change the top and left value of span and rather add `loop:true` to the `textillate`.

JS:

```
$(window).bind("load", function () {
ShowBrand();
$('.brand').textillate({ in : {
        effect: 'fadeInLeft'
    },
    out: {
        effect: 'fadeOutUp',
        callback: function () {
            ShowBrand()
        }
    },
    loop: true,
});
});

function ShowBrand() {
    var docHeight = $(document).height();
    var docWidth = $(document).width();
    $newSpan = $(".brand");
    spanHeight = $newSpan.height();
    spanWidth = $newSpan.width();
    maxHeight = docHeight - spanHeight;
    maxWidth = docWidth - spanWidth;
    $newSpan.show().css({
        top: Math.floor(Math.random() * maxHeight),
        left: Math.floor(Math.random() * maxWidth)
    });
}
```

Also, make sure you have `.brand` positioned.
CSS:

```
.brand{position:absolute;}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/y5C4G/6/

Comment: Thank you.There is a jumpy effect. The next apppearnce of the text starts even before the first one completes its animation(fadein+fadeout). You can check this in your fiddle. Tried increasing the seconds but no luck